# Pycharm 2019.3 runs VERY slow and takes forever to finish

Tags: debugging, pycharm, python-3.6

I have been using Pycharm 2019.3 with Python 3.6 as the interpreter and haven't had any issues until recently. The problem that I am having is that when I run a python script it takes a long time to finish. When I tried to stop the running script it takes about 5 minutes to fully terminate (stop) so I can run it again. Also, when I "terminate" the script I get a loading window saying "waiting for process to detach" and it takes  5 minutes, after that I can run the script and it runs fine but then again takes a long time to stop terminate completely so it can run again. It's frustrating since I need to run the scrip many times and I have to wait 5 min every time to re-run it :(

My configuration: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 16GB RAM

Any help is much appreciate it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some [other individuals](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004108559-Python-console-not-stopping-correctly-stuck) have had similar issues with the console needing to be re-run when the *stop* button is used in Pycharm. [Another person](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21940) claims that they have to click *stop* twice on Ubuntu in order to get a process to terminate.

It seems like problems with terminating processes in Pycharm and other JetBrains products have been a [long-standing issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17252) that is hard to fix. Beyond, reinstalling Pycharm and possibly reinstalling your Python interpreter, this issue might just unavoidable with your specific hardware/os configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried what others suggested in those links but nothing seemed to work. Then, out of nowhere it started working normally again! So strange... It might had to do with my some of my computer files being corrupted. I restarted my pc a couple of times. I am hoping that stays like this and doesnt get slow again!